# Convert string with format X.X.X to float

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm grabbing some data for a project that gives me a string in format X.X.X (example 15.23.1) which I need to somehow get down to 15.231. I thought I could convert the original string into a float and then use Convert.ToSingle to get it into a float but my attempts so far are failing.

Anyone got an easy solution for this?

Comment: what a strange format

Comment: How do you know it should be `15.231` instead of `1523.1` (or, for that matter, `15231`)?  More specifically, how would the code make this distinction?

Comment: No kidding. Just out of curiosity, what is the practical application for this?

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic I read that in Nicolas Cages voice. (sorry offtopic  xD)

Comment: One who downvoted all answers can leave any comments?

Comment: Lets say that we have a specification that has a number of tests. Some of the tests even have subtests. So we could have tests 1.1 and 1.2 along side 1.3.1 and 1.3.2. Ive got a regex to determine when we have multiple decimals. Users need to be able to match the number in the weird format against the specification for testing purposes but to sort a grid view by these numbers (and some may contain letters that need changing to magic numbers, yay!) we need to get them into a number format for proper grid view sorting.

Comment: Wouldn't you want 1.10 to sort after 1.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option with regex:

```
string str = "14.4.6";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\d+)(\.\d+)?\.?(\d+)?", "$1$2$3");
// parse string
```

Samples of input and output:

```
15.23.1 > 15.231
15.23   > 15.23
15      > 15
```

Comment: Love me a regex just wish I was a master with them

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the last `.` and then parse the rest of the string using `float.Parse` or `float.TryParse`

```
string str = "15.23.1";
str = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf('.'), 1);

float f;
if (float.TryParse(str, out f))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsing successful");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsing failed");
}
```

If you want Culture Insensitive parsing then you can try:

```
if (float.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out f))
```

Comment: @Habib `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); float.Parse("12.12");` throws an exception. It depends on the decimal separator. You should use an `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM, I am using `TryParse`, so no exception :P, but that itself is a separate issue, I can add that to my answer.

Comment: -1 OP _wants_ `Culture Insensitive`. He **must** use `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint and/or CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or else it will not work under certain circumstances.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM, I edited that almost 11 minutes ago, is there still something wrong ?

Comment: Using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is not optional, it's obligatory.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM, I am not sure what you are talking about ? `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is there in my answer. Are you concerned about my wording ?

Answer (score 2):

This will throw an exception if `str` has an unexpected format.

```
float f = float.Parse(str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf('.'), 1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Nope, that will return `15.23`

Comment: +1 the answer is correct! and I think this is the first answer?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to use [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) and [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "15.23.1";
s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf('.'), 1);

float f;
if(float.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out f))
{
   Console.WriteLine("YES");
   Console.WriteLine(f);
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("NO");
}
```

Output will be;

```
15,231
```

Comment: This won't work for `CultureInfo`s that have `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator != "."`

Comment: +1 , You should know that since my `CurrentCulture` is `fr-FR` by default, I have to deal with this all the time (parsing `floats`, `doubles`, `decimals` and `DateTimes`).

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM I think that doesn't matter because that's why I used `NumberStyles.Float` becuase it includes `AllowDecimalPoint`, `AllowLeadingWhite` and `AllowTrailingSign`

Comment: In `CurrentCulture fr-FR` `NumberDecimalSeparator == ","` and `NumberGroupSeparator == " "`!!

Comment: @SonerGönül No it matters : this prints false : `float foo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            Console.WriteLine(float.TryParse("123.12", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out foo));`

Comment: And this throws a `FormatException` : `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            float.Parse("123.12", NumberStyles.Float);`

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM But he is from _United Kingdom_, and he us probably english culture that's why using `InvariantCulture` seems ok to me. I didn't try _French_ culture but you say it fail, it fails.. But OP use english culture probably..

Comment: @SonerGönül you answer is right. I was referring to the comment "I think that doesn't matter". Yes, without using `InvariantCulture` the code works in almost all cases, but this is not recommended. If this code (without culture invariance) is executed in another system with a different culture it won't work (or generate unexpected results).